# Как унаследоваться от абстрактного класса?

Tags: java, android, классы

Здравствуйте.

Есть три класса. Обычный, абстрактный и наследник абстрактного.

Обычный класс содержит переменную абстрактного, куда после неких манипуляций запишется объект наследника.

Абстрактный:

```
    public abstract class LessonInfo {
    static String NAME;
    static int COUNT_QUESTION;
    static int[] PARTS;

    static String[] INFO_QUESTIONS;
    static int[] MARK_QUESTIONS;
}
```

Наследник:

```
    public class RussianInfo extends LessonInfo {

    static final String NAME = "Русский язык";
    static final int COUNT_QUESTION = 24;
    static final int[] PARTS = {24};

    static final String[] INFO_QUESTIONS = {"Определение главной информации текста", "Средства связи предложений",
                                "Лексическое значение слова", "Постановка ударения", "Употребление паронимов",
                                "Морфологические нормы", "Синтаксические нормы", "Правописание корней",
                                "Правописание приставок", "Правописание суффиксов", "Правописание глаголов и причастий",
                                "Правописание НЕ и НИ", "Слитное и раздельное написание слов", "Правописание -Н- и -НН_",
                                "Пунктуация", "Обособленные члены предложения", "Пунктуация во второстепенных чл. предложения",
                                "Пунктуация в СПП", "Пунктуация в разых тижах связи", "Смысловая целостность текста",
                                "Функционально-смысловые типы речи", "Лексическое значение слова", "Средства связи предложений",
                                "Средства выразительности"
                                };
    static final int[] MARK_QUESTIONS = {2,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,25};

}
```

Обычный (фрагмент):

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LessonInfo info;
    static LessonInfo lessonInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        lessonInfo = new RussianInfo();


    }
}
```

После команды "ОбычноеАктивити.lessonInfo.MARK_QUESTIONS[i]" приложение не вылетает.

Что не так? Думаю, накосячил с абстрактным классом и его наследником

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуй в абстрактном классе создать абстрактный метод `initVariables` и вызвать его в конструкторе абстрактного класса. В каждом из наследников реализовывать этот метод и инициализировать переменные именно в нем. Так же, не стоит в абстрактном классе переменные делать `static`, так как значение этой переменной будет одинаково для всех экземпляров класса.

Абстрактный:

```
public abstract class LessonInfo {
    public String name;
    public int countQuestion;
    public int[] parts;

    public String[] infoQuestions;
    public int[] markQuestions;

    public LessonInfo() {
        initVariables();
    }

    public abstract void initVariables();
}
```

Наследник:

```
public class RussianInfo extends LessonInfo{

    @Override
    public void initVariables() {
        name = "Русский язык";
        countQuestion = 24;
        parts = new int[]{24};

        infoQuestions = new String[]{"Определение главной информации текста", "Средства связи предложений",
                "Лексическое значение слова", "Постановка ударения", "Употребление паронимов",
                "Морфологические нормы", "Синтаксические нормы", "Правописание корней",
                "Правописание приставок", "Правописание суффиксов", "Правописание глаголов и причастий",
                "Правописание НЕ и НИ", "Слитное и раздельное написание слов", "Правописание -Н- и -НН_",
                "Пунктуация", "Обособленные члены предложения", "Пунктуация во второстепенных чл. предложения",
                "Пунктуация в СПП", "Пунктуация в разых тижах связи", "Смысловая целостность текста",
                "Функционально-смысловые типы речи", "Лексическое значение слова", "Средства связи предложений",
                "Средства выразительности"};
        markQuestions= new int[]{2,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,25};
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LessonInfo lessonInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lessonInfo = new RussianInfo();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "lessonInfo.name" + lessonInfo.name);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "lessonInfo.markQuestions" + lessonInfo.markQuestions.toString());
        Log.d("MainActivity", "lessonInfo.infoQuestions" + lessonInfo.infoQuestions.toString());
    }
}
```

Кстати, переменной `lessonInfo` тоже не нужно ставить модификатор `static`.

Comment: В принципе, можно обойтись без абстрактного метода `initVariables` и инициализировать переменные в конструкторе каждого наследника, но решение с абстрактным методом более красивое и явно дает понять, что переменные нужно инициализировать именно в этом методе Это уменьшает вероятность забыть проинициализировать переменные.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!

Comment: @ЕвгенийМанько, если ответ решает задачу вашу, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав галочу слева от тела ответа.

Answer (score 4):

Еще один вариант:

Абстрактный:

```
public abstract class LessonInfo {
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract int getCountQuestion();
    public abstract int[] getParts();

    public abstract String[] getInfoQuestions();
    public abstract int[] getMarkQuestions();
}
```

Наследник:

```
public class RussianInfo extends LessonInfo {

    private String name = "Русский язык";
    private int countQuestion = 24;
    private int[] parts = new int[]{24};

    private String[] infoQuestions = new String[]{"Определение главной информации текста", "Средства связи предложений",
                                                  "Лексическое значение слова", "Постановка ударения", "Употребление паронимов",
                                                  "Морфологические нормы", "Синтаксические нормы", "Правописание корней",
                                                  "Правописание приставок", "Правописание суффиксов", "Правописание глаголов и причастий",
                                                  "Правописание НЕ и НИ", "Слитное и раздельное написание слов", "Правописание -Н- и -НН_",
                                                  "Пунктуация", "Обособленные члены предложения", "Пунктуация во второстепенных чл. предложения",
                                                  "Пунктуация в СПП", "Пунктуация в разых тижах связи", "Смысловая целостность текста",
                                                  "Функционально-смысловые типы речи", "Лексическое значение слова", "Средства связи предложений",
                                                  "Средства выразительности"};
    private int[] markQuestions = new int[]{2,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,25};

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCountQuestion() {
        return countQuestion;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getInfoQuestions() {
        return infoQuestions;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getMarkQuestions() {
        return markQuestions;
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LessonInfo lessonInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lessonInfo = new RussianInfo();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "lessonInfo.name" + lessonInfo.getName());
        Log.d("MainActivity", "lessonInfo.markQuestions" + lessonInfo.getMarkQuestions().toString());
        Log.d("MainActivity", "lessonInfo.infoQuestions" + lessonInfo.getInfoQuestions().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Java полиморфизм работает только у нестатических методов.

Статические поля и методы не наследуются, а класс, поле которого будет использовано, вычисляется на этапе компиляции, по типу выражения слева от точки (в вашем случае `LessonInfo`). Сходным образом работает обращение к полям, объявленным с одним именем в суперклассе и в наследнике.

Если хочется сделать настройки через наследование, а не, например, через конфигурационные файлы, можно сделать как-то так:

```
public abstract class LessonInfo {
    public String name();
    public int questionCount();
    public int[] parts();

    public String[] infoQuestions();
    public int[] markQuestions();
}

public class RussianInfo extends LessonInfo {

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "Русский язык";
    }

    /* ..... */

    @Override
    public String[] infoQuestions();
        return new String[] {"Определение главной информации текста", "Средства связи предложений",
                                "Лексическое значение слова", "Постановка ударения", "Употребление паронимов",
                                "Морфологические нормы", "Синтаксические нормы", "Правописание корней",
                                "Правописание приставок", "Правописание суффиксов", "Правописание глаголов и причастий",
                                "Правописание НЕ и НИ", "Слитное и раздельное написание слов", "Правописание -Н- и -НН_",
                                "Пунктуация", "Обособленные члены предложения", "Пунктуация во второстепенных чл. предложения",
                                "Пунктуация в СПП", "Пунктуация в разых тижах связи", "Смысловая целостность текста",
                                "Функционально-смысловые типы речи", "Лексическое значение слова", "Средства связи предложений",
                                "Средства выразительности"
                            };
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LessonInfo info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        info = new RussianInfo();

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( info.infoQuestions() ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: В этом варианте, при вызове `infoQuestions()` каждый раз будет создаваться новый массив, что не очень хорошо, так как, возможно, данные массива понадобится менять извне и брать уже измененный массив.

Comment: А возможно наоборот, понадобится защитить этот массив от изменений извне.

Comment: Тоже верно, тут в зависимости от потребностей выбирать решение нужно.